# How to choose which file to debug in Visual Studio 2012 prof

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Kinda stupid question, but I've only been using this IDE for two days now. I havent found anything in google yet and I figured that once in a while you're entitled to a stupid question:

I have a project (or solution as Microsoft chose to call it) with two .cs-files. When I click on debug, it's alwys the same file that opens. How can I get VS to open the other .cs-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have multiple `static Main` methods in your project.  If that's the case then you have to set the startup object to the object that you want to run.

1. Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer and select
   Properties (or select Project >> *Projectname* Properties from the
   toolbar).
2. On the *Application* form, select the appropriate value
   for *Startup Object*.

Comment: I looked there. My project is called "test" and the two winforms-files I created are called login.cs and form1.cs. I have only two options in the starupt object menu, which are "not set" and Test.program. When I select the latter, it's the same winform that pops up. Does it hve to do with the order in which the winform files were created? Cos I created form1.cs before login.cs

Comment: Your program is going to start in the `static void Main()` function (whatever file that is within).  It won't execute any other code until that other code is actually called by the program (from an event, etc).

Comment: allright, i got it now. I changed the code accordingly. thanx all!